# transforming xml file

Tags: php, xml, xslt

How to perform a server-side transform on the products.xml using an
XSLT style sheet.The result will be an  XML file( item.xml) with the following structure 
 where ocshelf="yes" and  type= "cosmetic"

products.xml------------------------

```
<products>
<product onshelf=“yes” condition=“ok”>
<type>cosmetic</type>
<price>680</price>
<address>
<streetNo>1</streetNo>
<street>Jefer Street</street>
<suburb>Melbourne</suburb>
</address>
</product>
<product onshelf=“yes” condition=“ok”>
<type>noncosmetic</type>
<price>600</price>
<address>
<streetNo>2</streetNo>
<street>Colo Street</street>
<suburb>Melbourne</suburb>
</address>
</product>
</products>
```

item.xml---------------------------------

```
<products>
<product condition=“ok”>
<type>cosmetic</type>
<price>680</price>
<address>1 Jefer Street , Melbourne </address>
</product>
</products>
```

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: @ignacio actually i dont know how to transform products.xml into item.xml using xslt n php

Comment: Answerers here provide their services for essentially free, and most are reluctant to help if no effort whatsoever has been applied towards solving the problem, not even to the extent where a tutorial has been read.

Comment: Are you having trouble writing the XSLT code, or running it from PHP? Or both? To help you, we need to know where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="xs" 
                version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <products>
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                select="/products/product[@onshelf='yes' and type='cosmetic']"/>
        </products>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="product">
        <product condition="{@condition}">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </product>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="address">
        <address>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(streetNo, ' ', street, ', ', suburb)" />
        </address>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you are new to XSLT, I recommend taking a look at this thread for tutorial suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858345/xsltwhich-is-the-best-tutorial-you-would-like-to-recommend.